# Validating a datamodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a webAPI and the `datamodel`  looks as follows:

```
{
 "name" : "",
  "age" : ""
}
```

Since this is a 3rd party API that I created, there'll be many other developers who'll be trying to access it. One of the common mistake they make is that they at times forget some of the fields in the `datamodel`. For example, they may forget to enter a value for `age` at all.

So they'll only send `name` and not `age` as shown below.

```
{
     "name" : ""
}
```

How can I do a validation check from my controller to see if the developer has forgot to enter the attribute `age` in the JSON ?

I tried checking for null, but it didn't work.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveStudent([FromBody] Student stu)
{
    if(stu.age == null) { DISPLAY ERROR } // This doesn't work
...
}
```

Comment: What about model validation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a ViewModel.

Comment: Where is your Entity Framework Model class? Add that class into the question please?

Comment: you can use dataannotations on the viewmodel properties to add simple validation rules. It's probably in one of the Microsoft tutorials.

Comment: @TanvirArjel , not every Model class needs to be an Entity Framework Model class,

Comment: @Illep Please check my answer! Hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most microsoft web frameworks, you can use [DataAnnotatons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations) , checking the MSDN website, you can find an example of how to use [DataAnnotations with Json Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api), using the attributes you can specify Range, Required, etc for the incoming model,

Comment: out of curiosity, Are there any other method other than using DataAnnotation. This is for a viewModel .

Comment: If that is the data that you are receiving from a post, it does,just check if your model is valid, use `ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                           .Where(x=>x.Count>0)
                           .ToList();` to get the errors that are associated with the model

Comment: Sorry I saw your comment a bit late, if you want another way to validate your code, I would suggest maybe implement a IValidator interface, the interface would would idealy have a Validate() method, an errormessage List and any other items you see fit, then just class Validate() on your class after you recieve it from the post. You would need to implement your own validation logic though.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for model validation
Something like this;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveStudent([FromBody] Student stu)
{
if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            }
...
}
```

Comment: And use DataAnnotations attributes on your model as suggested by mahlatse

Answer (score 1):

Your model class should be as follows:

```
public class Student 
{
   [Required]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   [Required]
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
public class StudentController : Controller 
{
     public async Task<IActionResult> SaveStudent([FromBody] Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
              _dbContext.Students.Add(student);
              await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
              return Json(true)
        }

       return Json(false);
    }
}
```

Now you can show your custom error or success message on the client side based on `SaveStudent()` method returned output.